# SharePoint 2007 search query related to attachments in a list

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2007

Can sharepoint search work for list item attachments. I have a custom list where I am loading attachments. Can SharePoint search through the content of the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments in [this post](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15) it should index and search attachements in lists.

Answer (score 0):

It can search attachments as long as it has an IFilter for the file type, just like files in document libraries.